# 404 on setting an association resource

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

My first experiment with Spring Data Rest fails. I've taken the "Getting Started" and modified it a bit to create two entities that have a many-to-one relationships. The entities are `Book` and `Shelve` and many books can share a shelve.

The `Shelve` entity looks like this:

```
package hello;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Shelve
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private int length;

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }
}
```

The `Book` refers to it:

```
package hello;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Book
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne
    private Shelve shelve;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Shelve getShelve() {
        return shelve;
    }

    public void setShelve(Shelve shelve) {
        this.shelve = shelve;
    }
}
```

The full project is available [here in GitHub](https://github.com/Bert-R/spring-rest-data-experiment).

Now I can add a Shelve:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{  \"length\" : \"30\" }" http://localhost:8080/shelves
HTTP/1.1 201
Location: http://localhost:8080/shelves/1
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 17 Nov 2016 16:05:02 GMT

{
  "length" : 30,
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/shelves/1"
    },
    "shelve" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/shelves/1"
    }
  }
}
```

Then a book:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{  \"title\" : \"The Battle of Life\" }" http://localhost:8080/books
HTTP/1.1 201
Location: http://localhost:8080/books/1
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 17 Nov 2016 16:05:02 GMT

{
  "title" : "The Battle of Life",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/books/1"
    },
    "book" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/books/1"
    },
    "shelve" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/books/1/shelve"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I try to put the book on the shelve, but that fails:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "ContentType: text/uri-list" -d "http://localhost:8080/shelves/1" http://localhost:8080/books/1/shelve
HTTP/1.1 404
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 17 Nov 2016 16:05:02 GMT

{"timestamp":1479398702523,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/books/1/shelve"}
```

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Oliver Gierke on [the related JIRA ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-943), the issue is in the `curl` request. It should have a hypen in `Content-Type`:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type: text/uri-list" -d "http://localhost:8080/shelves/1" http://localhost:8080/books/1/shelve
HTTP/1.1 204
Date: Sat, 19 Nov 2016 16:50:24 GMT
```

So everything works as expected, provided you use it the right way :)

@Oliver: Thanks a lot!

Comment: And if you are using org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate or org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate then make sure you did not forget to specify your contentType when creating your HttpEntity as in following code:

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders()
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf('text/uri-list'))
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>('http://localhost:8003/myresources/' + myresource.id, headers)

Answer (score 0):

probably you need specify the link on 'Shelve' side, and try to add the book to the shelve

//Shelve model

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "shelve")
public Set<Book> getBooks() {
    return books;
}

public void setBooks(Set<Book> books) {
    this.books = books;
}
```

//curl add book to shelve

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "ContentType: text/uri-list" -d "http://localhost:8080/books/1" http://localhost:8080/shelve/1/books
```

Comment: That might work, but that's not the model I want. The code above obviously only explores Spring Data Rest. I need a ManyToOne.

Comment: @ Bert have you added @ onetomany otherside section and tried the ManyToOne addition?

Comment: No, I didn't do that, as I don't want to have that in my model. I need a one-way-navigable to-on relationship.